# How can i use max.retry.count in liquibase

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

In order to use retry.attempts in liquibase :

```
<sql>ALTER TABLE t set t.name = 'CI_CASE' where t.retry_attempts >= 1000</sql>
```

not sure how can i ADD a Column to table CI_CASE

so i tried a simpler statement:

```
<sql>ALTER TABLE CI_CASE ADD COLUMN TNUM</sql>
```

but i get Exception:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE CI_CASE ADD COLUMN TNUM: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

I have tried appending ";" semicolon, and trying:

```
<sql>ALTER TABLE t set t.name = 'CI_CASE' and t.column = 'TNUM' where t.retry_attempts >= 1000</sql>
```

which is my ultimate Goal , is to use retry.attempts for liquibase

so the error was due to Syntax, and the following SQL statement in the .sql file passed:

```
ALTER TABLE CI_CASE ADD TNUM varchar2(1) NOT NULL;
```

Now need to figure out how to use :

put ‘max.retry.count’ in to  liquibase.property file.

e.g parameter.max.retry.count=30

perhaps as an argument, to the :

```
<sqlFile path="oracle/schemas/ci_case.sql"/>
```

i tried:

ALTER TABLE CIS_CASE ADD TNUM varchar2(1) NOT NULL WHERE CIS_CASE.retry_attempts >=  ${max.retry.count};

```
Liquibase update Failed: Migration failed for change set edata-changelog.xml::2016-08-25-cnwill::CW:
00:03:34.886      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE CIS_CASE ADD TNUM varchar2(1) NOT NULL WHERE CIS_CASE.retry_attempts >=  $ax.retry.count}: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

notice the { and m , missing in the error log, not sure why is that so ?

i tried:

```
for Database/oracle/schemas/eldata/eldata-changelog.xml

<changeSet id="2016-08-25-cna-01" author="Ch Wills">
                <comment>
                        Testing retry logic on liquibase
                </comment>
                <sqlFile path="oracle/schemas/eldata/2016-08/2016-08-25-cna-01/20160825_01_upd-data-elis2data-cis_case_kr.sql"/>
        </changeSet>
```

This works, but now we want to incorporate a variable max.retry.count
So I use the property file:

```
liquibase.property
```

With:

```
parameter.max.retry.count=30
```

And call this in the changeset as:

```
<changeSet id="2016-08-25-cna-01" author="Ch Wills">
                <comment>
                        Testing retry logic on liquibase
                </comment>
                <sqlFile path="oracle/schemas/eldata/2016-08/2016-08-25-cna-01/20160825_01_upd-data-eldata-cis_case_kr.sql”/>
                    <property name="max.retry.count" value="100" />
        </changeSet>
```

Error:

```
 [ERROR] [system.err] Liquibase update Failed: Error parsing line 10730 column 50 of /opt/jenkins/workspace/EL-FT-DBV-LIQUIBASE-RETRY/Apps/Database/oracle/schemas/eldata/eldata-changelog.xml: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'. One of 
'{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":comment, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createView, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":renameView, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropView, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":insert, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addColumn, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":sql, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createProcedure, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":sqlFile, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":renameTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":renameColumn, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropColumn, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":mergeColumns, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifyDataType, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createSequence, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":alterSequence, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropSequence, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createIndex, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropIndex, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addNotNullConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropNotNullConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addForeignKeyConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropForeignKeyConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropAllForeignKeyConstraints, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addPrimaryKey, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropPrimaryKey, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addLookupTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addAutoIncrement, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addDefaultValue, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropDefaultValue, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addUniqueConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropUniqueConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":customChange, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":update, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":delete, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":loadData, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":loadUpdateData, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":executeCommand, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":stop, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":rollback, WC[##other:"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"], "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifySql}' is expected.
```

So that seems to be the list of property name’s I can use

Therefore it seems liqubibase does not have any “RETRY” property.

seems SQL itself provides looping based on the error code being received:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP  -- Try transaction at most 5 times.

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Try #' || i);

    BEGIN  -- sub-block begins

       SAVEPOINT start_transaction;

       -- transaction begins

       DELETE FROM results WHERE res_answer = 'NO';

       INSERT INTO results (res_name, res_answer) VALUES (name, answer);

       -- Nonunique name raises DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX.

       -- If transaction succeeded:

       COMMIT;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' succeeded.');
       EXIT;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' failed; trying again.');
        ROLLBACK TO start_transaction;    -- Undo changes.
        suffix := suffix + 1;             -- Try to fix problem.
        name := name || TO_CHAR(suffix);
    END;  -- sub-block ends

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Is that the only way, i can provide retry in liquibase for SQL ?  if so, then, is there a way i can use a variable in place of 5 , in the 1..5 loop ?

Comment: How & where exactly did you specify your parameter? Did you use a  [changelog parameter](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) for `max.retry.count`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "providing >= in terms of values"... Also, please follow the approach one problem = one question. New problem --> new question. Keeps answering easier.

Comment: can i specify the max.retry count as:
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd"
        logicalFilePath="elis2data-changelog.xml">
        <property name="max.retry.count" value="100" />

Comment: also in liquibase API, i could not see any mention of max.retry.count. I am using liquibase version 3.0.5

Comment: `max.retry.count` is just a variable (for your sql). You can name it whatever you want. I don't see how it should be mentioned in liquibase?

Comment: @Jens what i am trying to do is: RETRY an SQL statement N number of times if there is a lock on a table. So the max.retry.count would be a function of PLSQL ? since i am using Oracle as Database. so the max.retry.count must be implemented somewhere ? since it does not seem to be an arbitrary variable.

Comment: @Jens I ma just trying to understand how max.retry.count is available for SQL , is that part of Oracle PLSQL ? and what does it depend on ? and how its implemented. e.g. if the error code is NNNN, which signifies a lock on a table , THEN the SQL is retried ? or on other failures , can we specify failure or error conditions and codes upon which we can invoke the max.retry ? Excuse my ignorance with sql.

Comment: I don't know much about Oracle. Sorry, I can't help you with that.